# Issue with covariant in representational trait

Tags: scala, generics, covariance, type-parameter

Hi so I have a trait that takes some representation of itself as a type parameter. I also have a covariant type that it is encapsulating.

Here is my code:

```
trait ThingLike[+T, Repr <: ThingLike[T, Repr] {
   def +[S >: T](elem: S): Repr
   def +[S >: T](elem: S, elem2: S, elem3: S*): Repr = elems.foldLeft[Repr](this + elem + elem2)(_ + _)
}
```

I would imagine the above works, but the sbt compiler keeps on complaining about:

```
[error]  found   : S 
[error]  required: String 
[error]  def +[S >:T](elem: S, elem2: S, elems: S*): Repr = elems.foldLeft[Repr](this + elem)(_ + _)
```

I've even tried variants below:

```
trait ThingLike[+T, Repr <: ThingLike[T, Repr] {
   def +[S >: T, SRepr <: ThingLike[S, Repr]](elem: S): SRepr
   def +[S >: T, SRepr <: ThingLike[S, Repr]](elem: S, elem2: S, elem3: S*): SRepr = elems.foldLeft[SRepr](this + elem + elem2)(_ + _)
}
```

Not sure why the type String has to do with the problems outlined. It is kind of late at night. Any elegant way of solving this? Thanks!

Comment: I had to fix a couple of typos (`]` and `elems`) but after that it compiled without warning or error.

Comment: It might be the version of scala I am running. I'll try upgrading and see if that fixes the issue. Thanks :)